# Using PayPal subscription IPN fields to manage user accounts

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using PayPal to take subscription payments for access to a website service.

I'm using PayPal's IPN to manage the payments and user accounts.

I'm sending a custom random key to PayPal, unique to each user, when the subscription is first instantiated so the same key is sent back with every IPN. This means I can bind together my users table with my PayPal notifications very positively.

Accordingly I can now generate from my database a list of user_ids and notification details.

So now I need to figure out the best logic to use to calculate each users current payment status and, as a consequence, what to do with their account - whether to continue allowing access, suspend or even delete their user account. This decision will all come down to whether their payments are still coming through or not.

A bunch of interesting an varied data comes through on PayPal's IPN - most looks irrelevant in terms of user account management but a couple of columns look quite useful. Specifically...

1. Field `outstanding_balance` appears to contain exactly that - a value to 2dp of money still owing. So far during my testing this figure has only ever been 0.00
2. Field `txn_type` shows me any from a selection of different codes: subscr_signup (when the user initially sets up the subscription), subscr_payment (when a payment appears to be successful), subscr_cancel (this seems to appear whether the customer or vendor cancels the subscription), and subscr_eot (end of term - this one crops up shortly after the subscription is cancelled).

My impulse is to search the table for the most recent `txn_type="subscr_payment"` entry for each user account, and check the date this last notification arrived. If it is date stamped over, say, 28 days ago the account can be suspended... if it's over 56 days the account can be deleted.

Is this a good idea? Or is there better logic I can employ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this. Quite simple:

1. Don't grant access until you receive the first payment. You can get the intial signup and payment in either order.
2. PayPal will notify you if they cancel their subscription or it expires. When you get either of those, deny access as from the effective date.
3. If the most recent payment status on an account is 'reverse', suspend access until you either get 'cancel reverse' or the situation is sorted out in some other way.
4. Don't count the days. PayPal counts the days. All you can get from repeating that yourself is a disagreement, and guess who's right? PayPal. And guess who isn't wrong? The customer. You don't want to penalise the customer because PayPal got behind or had a different idea of 28 days from yours. You've handed responsibility for collections and renewals to PayPal: let them do it.
5. Beware of building policy into this. It should just be a mechanism, and it should be manually overridable. For example, the actual evaluation of whether this user has access to this product now mustn't be a computation over their payment history. Just a simple lookup of another table, which your IPN code can modify, but so can humans. For example: there is a dispute. You lost. You might well as a matter of business want to keep the customer alive for a grace period anyway. Alternatively you might *in extremis* want to fire the customer immediately, e.g. for usage violations.
6. You can ignore the balance field. The only important thing is the `txn_type`.

Comment: My situation is marginally different but I think the logic will be pretty similar. In my case the user sets up an account and uses it for a free trial period. They can do this without divulging any payment details... for the users piece of mind and good will. Then, towards the end of their free trial they are invited to subscribe. When notification arrives of a successful payment their account comes out of 'free trial' mode and into 'live' mode.

Comment: One potential stumbling point in checking for the most recent `txn_type` status is that at the start of the subscription two IPNs come in - `subscr_signup` and `subscr_payment`. This is why I thought about searching specifically for the most recent `txn_type=subscr_payment` and seeing how long ago it was

Comment: Can you elaborate on the 'reverse' and 'cancel reverse' status, please? Under what circumstances do these come in, how do I create these statuses with my test accounts, and what is the exact text that comes through?

Comment: See above about signup and first payment. When you have them both, create and enable the account. From there on its just a matter of reacting to further transactions. 'Reverse' comes in when there is a dispute, and cancel-reverse if it is resolved in your favor. Dunno how you synthesize them in the sandbox. The txn_types are all documented in the IPN Guide. Re trials, PayPal already support that and it fits into the scheme above. Can't remember the details and I'm away until Friday but I believe you get an initial payment of zero,

Comment: I have been reviewing the IPN guide - I'm just wanting to find the opinion of someone who has been through it already :) So, assuming my subscription period is 28 days, do you think it safe to say that if `subscr_payment` has appeared within the last 28 days then everything is OK. If `subscr_payment` has *not* appeared in the last 28 days then there has been a problem with payment and the account should be suspended?

Comment: You don't even have to worry about the 28 days. If you don't get a payment you will get something else: a fail, a cancel, a reversal, or an EOT. All you have to do is act on the event you get.

Comment: I'm just really talking about a generic failure - rather than testing for all scenarios - cancel, eot, etc... I can just test for whether it is a successful payment or not. I'm only interested in the payment being successful - do I really need to care *why* a payment has been unsuccessful?

Comment: You need to care what happens at each renewal date. Either you got the money or you didn't. PayPal will infallibly send you an event that says which and why. You don't have to subdivide all the failure cases but you do have to notice the event. They're already counting the 28 days: no need to duplicate that.

Comment: Thanks, @EJP - you've been a great help :) I think I'm figuring my strategy now.